# Question about "Arch 1 x 2 Inverted"

Tags: building, design, architecture, window

So, I'm creating round windows for my temple build.  My current approach uses 2  1x4 arches (the stubby kind) with one of them upside down and some complicated mechanisms for keeping it in place.  Then, I insert a [Dish 2 x 2 Inverted (Radar) with Radial Cockpit Window Pattern](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=4740pb005&C=0#T=C&C=0) between the 2 of them.  I recently came across the [arch 1x2 inverted](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=78666&C=86#T=C&C=86). I'm wondering if this could be used to do the same thing without some of the complexity of inserting an upside-down piece.  I don't have one at the moment so can anyone verify this?

Here are some pictures that show what I'm currently doing:
[image: window1]
[image: window2]
[image: window3 - complete]

Comment: pictures added.

Comment: According to a quick LeoCAD model, it looks like it should work, altough there'll be a tiny gap on the bottom part since the inverted arch doesn't exactly have a round shape. Consider also using [41682 bracket 2x2 - 1x2](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=41682) to simplify the SNOT support for the window. But I guess those would fit better as an extra answer to your question from last year.